# What is the purpose of a trunk port in a network switch?

Tags: switch, trunk

I have recently taken over responsibility of the management of the switches in my apartment complex. We two switches, 1 and 2, the fiber connection to the internet is connected to switch 1. Switch 2 is connected to Switch 1 through an ethernet cable. Switch 2 is configured so that the port that connects the two switches has a trunk option activated. From what I gather this is normal (all the outgoing traffic through this switch is sent through this port?).

However, in switch 1 there is also a port with a trunk option activated. However, this port is the port that is connected to the apartment of the old responsible of the switches in our apartment complex. Finally my question is, is this normal, or has this guy been up to something fishy?

edit:
The model of the switch is HP ProCurve Switch 2650  J4899A.

Under Switch Configuration -> Port/Trunk Settings

Type      Enabled      Mode      Flow Ctrl  Group  Type

10/100TX  | Yes      Auto          Disable    Trk1   Trunk

Comment: Hi Henrik,you'll have to specify the model of switch and preferably include configs.  The problem is that the term "trunk" is not well-defined between vendors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input, is there a specific configuration you are looking for? I will try to find the specific setting. The row with the port in question says: Type      Enabled      Mode      Flow Ctrl  Group  Type
10/100TX  | Yes      Auto          Disable    Trk1   Trunk

Comment: You really need to tell us how the network devices are connected (a diagram would be great), the network device models, and the network device configurations. Full configurations are preferred because there are often configuration in various places in a device that can affect how a device operates.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input.
I now realize my knowledge about this is maybe too limited to even ask a question. I will try to draw a diagram tonight. I am not sure what full configuration means, but I will return with as much relevant information I can.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing inherently "fishy" about running a trunk port to "the apartment of the person formerly responsible for administering the switches" (which is what I decipher you to mean) - as a network manager I certainly prefer to be able to troubleshoot a network from the comfort of my office rather than having to drag a laptop down to the network hub area. The reality is that that person's (or yours, now) integrity is the only thing standing between a person with network administrative powers and other people's data - integrity is part of the job, and it is not changed (for better, or for worse) by having a trunk port.

If this person is no longer responsible for that function, then it might well be appropriate to turn that off - it in part depends on what the VLAN configuration of the switches is and how service is provided to apartments (each on it's own VLAN? Some other way? you need to understand it before you can effectively manage it.) Depending on switch software, some have very simple "trunk" setups where everything is always on a trunk, others can have a trunk that only has a few specific VLANs on it, such as the management VLAN and the access VLAN for the particular apartment. If the setup is that it's "all" for a trunk, the only way to get the management VLAN to an apartment along with the apartment access VLAN would be to send everything there, and then depend on integrity.

If the transfer of responsibility is not overtly hostile, you might want to discuss how things are set up with the "Old Responsible" - if you can't do that, you may have a lot of self-education to accomplish in a hurry.

Comment: Thank you for this response! This was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: The previous network manager moved out a long time ago and I was recently informed about the system. I therefore have a non-existent relationship to him. I thought that trunk meant that all traffoc was routed through this port and I could see no practical use for that. Again, thank you for enlightening me. And yes, I do have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The term trunk port means different things to diffrent vendors. For example, in Cisco it is a port that uses multiple VLANs normally used to connect two switches together so all vlans traverse the network. It can be used for other devices like ip phones that need more than 1 vlan. In HP it is the combining of multiple interfaces between switches to carry more traffic. It's a bundle or aggregation of interfaces(ports) via programming and physical connection.